# Foreach in Get-ADUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I've tried lots of different combinations at this point and I'm coming up dry. I have a CSV file that contains usernames (**Users**) of people in the format of 117321, which refers to their login name. I'm trying to get the homedirectory path of all these users and export them to a CSV. Here's what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to work. I've even tried filter.

```
$InputFile = 'C:\Users.csv'
$Users = Import-CSV $InputFile
$OutputFile = 'C:\Directory Results.csv'

$HomeDirOutput = ForEach ($User in $Users) {
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountName=$user)" -Properties homedirectory
}

$HomeDirOutput | Export-Csv $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

All I'm getting is a blank spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sAMAccountName is a valid value to pass to the `-Identity` parameter of Get-ADUser.  Assuming that the CSV contains a column "AccountName", you should be able to do

```
Import-CSV -Path $InputFile | ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -Identity $_.AccountName -Property sAMAccountName,HomeDirectory } | SelectObject -Property sAMAccountName,HomeDirectory | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path $OutputFile -Append
```

(after making sure that the output file doesn't already exist).

Comment: The column name is "User" and I don't need the sAMAccountName if I can just do $_.User

Comment: Then change `-Identity $_.AccountName` to `-Identity $_.User`. If this wasn't obvious, please take some time to do some studying of PowerShell; I recommend Manning Publications _Learn Windows PowerShell in a Month of Lunches_.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work. Additionally, is there way to only display if they're a certain "memberof"?

Comment: You will need to read up in detail on the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet, paying special attention to the `-Filter` parameter.